# "IOException: The process cannot access the file ..... because it is being used by another process." after file write operation

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Two different codes gives the same result. A file upload or write occurs to a folder successfully but when another file with the same destination is uploaded or written, I got ioexception. Another process is using it. I can't even delete file using explorer. IIS + Asp.net core. So the first time upload produces a lock.

Codes:

1

```
using (var writer = System.IO.File.CreateText(webRootPath+"/uploads/"+filename)){
    writer.WriteLine(content);
}
```

2

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(webRootPath+"/uploads/"+formFile.FileName, FileMode.Create)){
    await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks good - `using` should dispose resource as soon as data is written. Are you sure that it's your app is holding reference? Maybe some antivirus is checking your file? You can use [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to check what process is locking your file.

Comment: There is no antivirus software. And I've checked with Process Explorer, it could not find any process that holds the file.

Comment: I made a simple console programs that executes code (1) two times in a row, overwriting same file. It works. Look for other places in your code that may hold the lock. May be when reading file to client?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved. Another process is using file in my code. Thanks Dimitry